# Replace null values in dataframe with other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, key-value

I have two dataframe and I want to replace null values with other dataframe on key(X) with how ='left' (DF1). Thank you so much.

```
DF1
X | Y
1 | a
2 | NaN
3 | c 

DF2
X | Y
1 | a 
2 | b
3 | NaN
4 | d

OUTPUT
X | Y
1 | a
2 | b
3 | c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dictionary from the rows of df2 and use that dictionary with [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

da1 = [[1, 'a'],
       [2, np.nan],
       [3, 'c']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=da1, columns=['X', 'Y'])

da2 = [[1, 'a'],
       [2, 'b'],
       [3, np.nan],
       [4, 'd']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=da2, columns=['X', 'Y'])

mapping = dict(zip(df2.X, df2.Y))
df1.Y = df1.Y.fillna(df1.X.map(mapping))
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
   X  Y
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) as:

```
df1['Y'] = df1['X'].map(df2.set_index('X')['Y']).fillna(df1['Y'])
```

Or using `np.where` as:

```
df1['Y'] = np.where(df1.Y.isnull(),df1['X'].map(df2.set_index('X')['Y']),df1['Y'])
```

---

```
print(df1)
   X  Y
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
```